# Chrome extension — cannot get data from dom

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Recently I've been working on a chrome extension.

I've successfully get $0 in devtools.js

```
var backgroundPageConnection = chrome.runtime.connect({
    name: 'devtools'
});

backgroundPageConnection.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
    // Handle responses from the background page, if any
    chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval(`setSelectedElement($0)`, {
        useContentScriptContext: true
    });
});
```

However, in contentscript.js, I want to get data from $0

```
function setSelectedElement(el) {
    var widget = $(el).data("__widget__");
    // eval widget is null
    var id = $(el).attr("id");
    // eval id is string
}
```

Simply, everything get by `data()` is null

I'm very confused, I can get stuff by `attr()` but cannot by `data()`

Am I missing some permissions?

here is the manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Export",  
    "manifest_version":2,
    "version": "4.0.1",  
    "description": "Export Json",
    "browser_action": {  
      "default_title": "Export",
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "content_scripts": 
    [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["js/core.js", "js/contentscript.js"],
            "run_at": "document_end"
        }
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["js/background.js"]
    },
    "devtools_page": "devtools.html",
    "web_accessible_resources": ["js/inject.js"]
}
```

Comment: Explanation and solutions: [Insert code into the page context using a content script](//stackoverflow.com/a/9517879)

Comment: What is the element? What is the data?

Comment: @DanielMöller, it's not important. The difference is caused by isolated world of content scripts, which is explained in the answer linked above.

Comment: @DanielMöller Its an JSON Object

Comment: @wOxxOm Do you mean I need run $(el).data() in inject.js?

Comment: If your inject.js runs in a script element as explained in the linked answer, then yes.